# C# Winforms cannot start form2 from form1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser, file-not-found

I'm making a WinForms application using `EasyTabs` from NuGet. I went over to [EasyTabs' GitHub page](https://github.com/lstratman/EasyTabs/), and used [their code](https://github.com/lstratman/EasyTabs/tree/master/TestApp) as a template for my project.

In my `program.cs`, I start `TestApp.TestApp()` with the line `TestApp testApp = new TestApp();`.

The latter line causes an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Win32Interop.User32, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

It also tells me:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in TestApp.dll

In my `TestApp.cs`, when I change `public partial class TestApp : TitleBarTabs` to `public partial class TestApp : System.Windows.Forms.Form` inside the namespace, the error is no longer encountered so it must be something to do with EasyTabs itself.

Below is the code where the error-causing line "`TestApp testApp = new TestApp();`" is found, the method `main` being inside the `Program` class, in `Program.cs`.

```cs
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    TestApp testApp = new TestApp();

    testApp.Tabs.Add(
        new TitleBarTab(testApp)
        {
            Content = new TabWindow
            {
                Text = "New Tab"
            }
        });
    testApp.SelectedTabIndex = 0;

    TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.Start(testApp);

    Application.Run(applicationContext);
}
```

Any help as to why the system can't start `TestApp()` and how this can be fixed it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you look at your references for your project, is `Win32Interop.User32` listed, and is its `Path` property valid?

Comment: https://github.com/lstratman/Win32Interop (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Win32Interop.User32/)

Comment: @TimothyG. sorry, I'm new in C#, and I don't understand how to set the `Path` property. All I've done so far is reference the package like this: `using Win32Interop`.

Comment: @AlphaHowl see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHRpC.png) for what I mean.  As part of the example project, Win32Interop.User32 needs to be added as a reference.  What is probably happening is your project cannot find the reference to Win32Interop.User32.  If this is the case, there should be a small yellow triangle on the Win32Interop.User32 reference in your project (or, it might not be present at all in your reference list) - you might need to do a [nuget restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-packages-automatically-using-visual-studio)

Comment: @TimothyG. ok, thank you